# MS Excel - Sort and Rank Multiple Scores/Numbers in Descending Order

Tags: excel, sorting, range, ranking

I am looking for a MS Excel Ranking Formula solution, without the use of VBA/Macros or MS Excel's built-in sort function, that will allow me to sort multiple columns in Descending Order containing Ranks (i.e., RANK 1, RANK 2, and RANK 3) against a Primary Field (i.e., PLAYER) and re-sort list in Descending order.

SAMPLE: 
Triple Ranking And Tie Breaking (Unsorted Ranking)

[image]

RESULTS: Sorted Ranking in Adjacent Columns in Descending Order:
Sort by Column G (RANK 1), then by, Column H (RANK 2) and then by Column I (Rank 3) with matching/corresponding Player Name in Column J (PLAYER).

[image]

Comment: This can all be done utilizing the sorting feature in Excel.  Look at the ribbon and click the sort button.  add the levels you want to sort by.

Comment: As I indicated, I am looking for a MS Excel Formula that will allow me to do the same, without the use of the Excel Feature or Macro...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably easier to do this with the sort, but here's what you can do:

Make a new column next to player and call it "Overall Rank"

`=RANK(A2,A$2:A$26)+SUMPRODUCT(--(A2=A$2:A$26),--(B2<B$2:B$26))+SUMPRODUCT(--(A2=A$2:A$26),--(B2=B$2:B$26),--(C2<C$2:C$26))`

That will give you an overall rank, the resorting part is trivial, you will do an index match for each column.

Column G would be: `=INDEX(A$2:A$26,MATCH(ROW()-1,E$2:E$26))`

Column E is where the overall ranking formula would go.

Explanation of the ranking formula:

RANK() is pretty obvious, that's the rank on rank1.

The first SUMPRODUCT adds up all players that have the same rank1 and a higher rank2. `--` turns TRUE,FALSE into 1,0.

The second SUMPRODUCT adds up all players that have the same rank1, the same rank2, and a higher rank3.

Comment: the `SUMPRODUCT`s could be replaced with `COUNTIFS` if you are more comfortable using that formula

Comment: Hi Neil, Thanks - I inputted the "Overall Rank" formula data in Column G and it worked fine, by aggregating and combining all three (3) Rank fields in to one composite score/rank.  Unfortunately, when I copied the INDEX MATCH formula in Column G, whereas your Index points to Column "A$2:A$26" to return matching name, I corrected it by referencing the formula to return the matching name located in Column D$2:D$26.  When doing so, it repeats the same name David G1 through G9, then Elizabeth G10 through G18, etc.  Are you able to further assist

Comment: If you post screenshots of what you have then maybe. I'm not sure where you put each formula.